# Helmholtz decomposition under change is Riemmanian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Let us consider $(\Omega,g_1)$ be the smooth Riemannian manifold.
If $h$ is a tensor field of rank $m$, its total covariant derivative $\nabla h$ induced by the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ is an $(m+1)$-tensor field defined as follows:
$$
\nabla h\left(Z, Y_1, \ldots, Y_m\right)=Z\left(h\left(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m\right)\right)-\sum_{i=1}^m h\left(Y_1, \ldots, \nabla_Z Y_i, \ldots, Y_m\right)
$$
However, if $h$ is symmetric, $\nabla h$ is in general not symmetric. We can make it symmetric by applying the symmetrization operator $\sigma$, defined as
$$
\sigma(\nabla h)\left(Y_1, \ldots, Y_{m+1}\right)=\frac{1}{(m+1) !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{m+1}} \nabla h\left(Y_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, Y_{\sigma(m+1)}\right)
$$
where $S_{m+1}$ is the set of permutations of $\{1,2, \ldots, m+1\}$
Denote symmetrised covarient derivative $d^s_{g_1}$ by  $d^s_{g_1}:=\sigma \circ \nabla: C^{\infty}\left(S^m\left(T^* M\right)\right) \rightarrow C^{\infty}\left(S^{m+1}\left(T^* M\right)\right)$ where $\sigma $ is symmetrisation operator.

It is known that for $g$ smooth enough, each symmetric tensor $f \in \mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)$ admits a unique orthogonal decomposition $f=f^s+d v$ into a solenoidal tensor $\mathcal{S} f:=f^s$ and a potential tensor $\mathcal{P} f:=d v$, such that both terms are in $\mathrm{L}^2(\Omega), f^s$ is solenoidal, i.e., $\delta_ {g_1} f^s=0$ in $\Omega$, and $v \in \mathrm{H}_0^1(\Omega)$ (i.e., $v=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ ) where $\delta_{g_1}$ is adjoint of $d^s_{g_1}$.

In order to construct this decomposition, introduce the operator $\Delta^s=\delta_ {g_1} d_ {g_1} $ acting on vector fields. This operator is elliptic in $\Omega$, and the Dirichlet problem satisfies the Lopatinskii condition. Denote by $\Delta_D^s$ the Dirichlet realization of $\Delta^s$ in $\Omega$. Then
$$
v=\left(\Delta_D^s\right)^{-1} \delta_ {g_1} f, \quad f^s=f-d_ {g_1}\left(\Delta_D^s\right)^{-1} \delta _ {g_1} f
$$

> My question is that for metric $g_1$ we have unique orthogonal decomposition. But if we change Riemmanian metric to $g_2$ do we get certain guage condition or some relation in terms of $g_2$ and $g_1$.

Also I know one result which states that
for each $g \in \mathrm{C}^1(\bar{\Omega})$, the maps
$$
\left(\Delta_D^s\right)^{-1}: \mathrm{H}^{-1}(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathrm{H}_0^1(\Omega), \quad \mathcal{P}, \mathcal{S}: \mathrm{L}^2(\Omega) \longrightarrow \mathrm{L}^2(\Omega)
$$
are bounded and depend continuously on $g$.

But I dont know if there is any guage condition if we change two Riemmmanian metric.

Any help or hint or refernce will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe Lemma 1 from this article helps you https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0408/0408075.pdf

Comment: PS: Are you Gunther's student?